# Can we have two canvases in an activity ? (OR) Having a canvas outside the onDraw() is not working

Tags: android, graphics

```
@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Draw graphic objects
         .....
             }

         public void displayCalc(){

           //Do some calculation & display results near these graphic objects
            String result = String.valueOf(value);

             //Do some calculation

              //Display Calculated values
             Canvas c =new Canvas();
             Paint paint = new Paint();
             paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
             paint.setAntiAlias(true);
             paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             c.drawText(result,200,300,paint);
                     }
```

But if i have the same thing in the function onDraw it works fine. **I would like to know why or what changes i have to make to get it working**

```
   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // Draw graphic objects 
    //Do some calculation & display results near these graphic objects
     .....
     String result = String.valueOf(value);

        //Display Calculated values
         Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         canvas.drawText(result,200,300,paint);
}
```

Comment: Which one doesn't work? The first one looks like you're drawing to a canvas that isn't associated with a surface, so I'd be expecting that to be the one that fails (well... doesn't display anything).

Comment: sorry i missed out some thing ! I have edited now. Its the first one doesnt display anything

Comment: How is displayCalc called?  Is it called on the UI thread?

Comment: As you've said below, duplicate of your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635434/android-text-not-visible-on-writing-using-drawtext .  Try to avoid asking the same question twice...

Comment: @forsvarir, Its not exactly the same question, thats a problem i was facing with AsyncTask . (or) how to use canvas with AsyncTasks ! Btw my displayCalc is called from Oncreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to implement some kind of double buffering, you might want to take a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/8d1243c33f9b7b6e?pli=1)

I think your problem is that you need to create a bitmap, then attach the canvas to it, something like:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

// then draw to the canvas..
// and when you're happy, draw the bitmap onto the canvas supplied to onDraw.
```

Just creating a canvas, doesn't make it appear on the screen.

You may also want to take a look at: [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-1)

If you have a surfaceView, then you can do something like this (don't have a compiler, but hopefully you get the gist):

```
SurfaceView view = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.view);

SurfaceHolder holder = view.getHolder(); // save this where it can be accessed by your function

Canvas c 
try  {
    c = holder.lockCanvas();
    // draw stuff
}
finally {
    if(null != c) {
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use surfaceview for the first time. I wil let you know if it works. Thanks for the pointers !

Comment: I tried the tutorial which you pointed out. I downloaded the code given in the tutorial and i see on running for a minute it crashes/freeze. As it runs out of memory. Any ideas ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650810/canvas-and-surfaceview-example-crash-freeze-memory-leak

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two SurfaceViews, than simply add them to your layout and give them both an own thread (or combine both drawings in one thread).

I don't get it why you want to draw on a separate canvas in your first method sample... Maybe you provide more information for what you try to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635434/android-text-not-visible-on-writing-using-drawtext has some more information

Comment: OnDraw(Canvas canvas) gets called and i try to draw a graphic object. Then After that i keep retrieving data from Dataoutputstream and i try to display next to the graphic object.