# How to get frame rate on Android game

Tags: android, frame, frame-rate

I have tried two methods to get android fps:
 1. dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency ...
 2. dumpsys gfxinfo ...
Both of them were worked on a normal app view,but when it comes to a game view,I got nothing. I know GameBench can catch fps on game view,but how it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672503/android-how-to-find-the-frame-rate-of-a-device

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want , in the command 'dumpsys display' , the fps is device standard fps, it is a constant，what I need is the real time value...

Comment: I see that an external API provides this info: https://github.com/friendlyrobotnyc/TinyDancer. Not sure, if the same is provided by android. Never needed to query real time value. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989267/3991696

Comment: If you got apk source code you can use TinyDancer, but I don't have the apk source code....so ...I am sorry to tell you it is no use for me..sad..